# Constraints Problems with table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

[image: Table View image]

I have problems with constraints in table view cell. As you can see in the image above , I tried to constrain the label on the far right so that label will be closer to the right right edge. But that isn't reflecting on the ipad in preview. Whats wrong? and How do solve this problem ? Thanks for any help !

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have given it a colored background its still not moving towards the right edge

Comment: Well, build and run instead of relying on preview. If it still isn’t working, use the View Debugger to see what’s going on.

Comment: Thank you !. Now I feel really dumb. But I wonder why it doesn't show in the preview .

Comment: Because it's only a prototype cell. When you run the app you get _real_ cells. That's important to know so I'm actually going to give that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prototype cell in the storyboard is just that: a prototype. It isn't "real". It will be *used* as a cell when the app runs, and layout will occur. But the Preview in the storyboard in Xcode (in your version of Xcode) doesn't reflect any of that.

So the only way to see the effect of your constraints is to build and run the app in an appropriate Simulator.